# Is there a way to refer to the result of the previous command in PSCi?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, purescript

Coming from Haskell, I'm accustomed to using `it` to refer to the result of the previous command in GHCi:

```
ghci> 1+1
2
ghci> :type it
it :: Num a => a
ghci> it*2
4
```

I went looking to see if there was something similar in the PureScript REPL, but I couldn't find anything about it on the ["Differences from Haskell" page in the PureScript docs](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Differences-from-Haskell.md) (which makes a certain kind of sense now that I've had some time to think about it, since `it` is a specific feature of GHCi, not of the Haskell language itself), or in the [PSCi documentation](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/PSCi.md). In GHCi I can `:show bindings` to discover that `it` has been bound, but PSCi's `:show` command doesn't accept the `bindings` argument, and from the built-in PSCi help `:?` it's not obvious to me if there's a different command that does the same thing. (I know PSCI's `:browse` lets you examine the functions from a specific module, so since errors reported in PSCi often begin with `Error found: in module $PSCI` I tried `:browse $PSCI`, but this produces an indentation error.)

Some errors I've encountered seem to suggest that PSCi *is* trying to bind the result of a computation to the name `it` (I've cut some whitespace but otherwise this is copied verbatim from a fresh `spago repl` session in a toy project—note the final line, `in value declaration it`):

```
> import Prelude
> 1+'a'
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at :1:3 - 1:6 (line 1, column 3 - line 1, column 6)
  Could not match type
    Char
  with type
    Int
while checking that type Char
  is at least as general as type Int
while checking that expression 'a'
  has type Int
in value declaration it
```

But after a successful computation, `it` isn't available:

```
> 1+1
2
> it
Error found:
at <internal>:0:0 - 0:0 (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
  The value of it is undefined here, so this reference is not allowed.
```

This is a [`CycleInDeclaration` error](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/CycleInDeclaration.md), which is different from the [`UnknownName` error](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/UnknownName.md) produced when trying to use some other undefined name like `x` or `foo`. This all makes me suspect there is something special going on with `it` and I'm just missing something obvious about how to make it available for use in the REPL, but as someone brand new to PureScript, I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: Have you tried `x = it`?

Comment: Just tried `x = it`—there's no error immediately after I do that, but if I then try to use `x` in any way on subsequent lines, I get two `CycleInDeclaration` errors, one for `x` and one for `it`. (And this is still different from `y = foo`, which errors immediately with `Unknown value foo`.)

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Sorry, I don't think there is a way to do that in PureScript.